How do I assign a result depending on date using dynamic formula in excel?
I have two tables:
The first is a table of roles where each person is in a team but person c has changed teams in June:



Name
Team
Start Date
End Date




a
x
01-Jan
01-Dec


b
y
01-Jan
01-Dec


c
x
01-Jan
01-Jun


c
y
01-Jun
01-Dec



The second is a table of signings where it has the name of who signed it and when it was signed. What I need is a dynamic array formula that will show the team name of that person at the time of signing so signing 5 would be when person c was in team x, but signing 6 was when c was in team y. Person d doesn't exist in the role table so would need to show "not found"



Signing
Name
Date Of Signing
Team
Expected




1
a
01-Mar

x


2
a
01-Apr

x


3
b
01-Jan

y


4
b
01-Jun

y


5
c
01-Feb

x


6
c
01-Jun

y


7
d
01-Jul

Not Found




Try using XLOOKUP() function, btw to spill can use either BYROW() or MAP():


=XLOOKUP(1,(B8=$A$2:$A$5)*(C8>=$C$2:$C$5)*(C8<$D$2:$D$5),$B$2:$B$5,"Not Found")


Using MAP():
=MAP(B8:B14,C8:C14,LAMBDA(α,δ,
 XLOOKUP(1,(α=A2:A5)*(δ>=C2:C5)*(δ<D2:D5),B2:B5,"Not Found")))


Using BYROW():
=BYROW(B8:C14,LAMBDA(α,
 XLOOKUP(1,(TAKE(α,,1)=A2:A5)*(TAKE(α,,-1)>=C2:C5)*
 (TAKE(α,,-1)<D2:D5),B2:B5,"Not Found")))


And Spill output without using LAMBDA() helper functions:
=LET(a, MMULT((C8:C14>=TOROW(C2:C5))*
              (C8:C14<TOROW(D2:D5))*
              (B8:B14=TOROW(A2:A5)),
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:D5))),
     IFNA(INDEX(B2:B5,IF(a=0,NA(),a)),"Not Found"))


